# How do I align the form fields horizontally in one line?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to align and resize the form fields in the link attached horizontally and in one line. Any ideas on how I could ?

https://beyondcondo.com/testpage/

Comment: Post your code on here in a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:flex` on `.idx-omnibar-form form` and `flex:1;` on its children elements as shown below:

```css
.idx-omnibar-form{
display:flex;
align-items:flex-end;
}
.idx-omnibar-form *{
flex:1;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_code et_pb_module  et_pb_code_0">
  <form class="idx-omnibar-form idx-omnibar-extra-form">
    <label for="omnibar" class="screen-reader-text" style="display:none">City, Zip Code, Address, or Listing ID</label>
    <input id="omnibar" class="idx-omnibar-input idx-omnibar-extra-input" type="text" placeholder="City, Zip Code, Address, or Listing ID">
    <div class="idx-omnibar-extra idx-omnibar-price-container idx-omnibar-min-price-container"><label>Price Min</label><input class="idx-omnibar-min-price" type="number" min="0"></div>
    <div class="idx-omnibar-extra idx-omnibar-price-container idx-omnibar-max-price-container"><label>Price Max</label><input class="idx-omnibar-price" type="number" min="0"></div>
    <div class="idx-omnibar-extra idx-omnibar-bed-container"><label>Beds</label><input class="idx-omnibar-bed" type="number" min="0"></div>
    <div class="idx-omnibar-extra idx-omnibar-bath-container"><label>Baths</label><input class="idx-omnibar-bath" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" title="Only numbers and decimals are allowed"></div>
    <button class="idx-omnibar-extra-button" type="submit" value="Search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span>Search</span></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for the prompt response. I made the update. Now i see the following. Please refresh the page. or click on the below  URL   https://beyondcondo.com/testpage/

Comment: @Dg20 Modified the code again for CSS, try that now.

Comment: No ! Do you want me to make that change?

Comment: That worked thank you so much. Also, any recommendations on how to make the form fields align veritically when I resize the screen ? or on a mobile,table view ?

Comment: @Dg20 Don't forget to mark this answer :) and I can't look at your media query CSS but in that basically just add this to ".idx-omnibar-form{ flex-direction:column;}"

Comment: the mobile view appears to be an issue .. Can you open the page on a mobile device. The styling appears to be offf. Any ideas on how i could fix this ?

Comment: Like I said modify your media query. @media only screen and ( max-width: 980px ){.idx-omnibar-form{ flex-direction:column;}}

Comment: Aah yeah so i tried that but it only partially fixed the issue. The form fields are vertically aligned but  I would rther prefer them to fit in 3 rows instead of 5 that it currently shows. The address bar is too big .. so I am thinking if I can align the remaining 4 fields in two rows that would be ideal . Can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot preach enough about css flexbox. Since it has become cross-browser compatible I have been using it on everything and I haven't written `float` in almost a year.

If this were my project I would add flex to the parent container (in your code the parent is `<form>`) to get all of the children inline together. There are also other flex attributes you can use to adjust their positioning within the parent container. In the example below I have chose `justify-content:space-between` to spread the children out so they go right to the corners. If you wanted them centered you could choose `justify-content:center`!
Flex also lets you adjust vertically. Here I have chosen `align-items:stretch` so that all of the child divs are the same height as the tallest sibling.

Then all you need to do is align the content inside of the child divs. You can flex those too if you want!

Read more about flex here:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.parent{

  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:stretch;

}

.child{
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div><!-- child -->
  <div class="child">
    2
  </div><!-- child -->
  <div class="child">
    3
  </div><!-- child -->
</div><!-- parent -->
```